# Unable to access class function using pointers

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

When trying to access the functions of my class members, I am unable to find them when using pointers.This forms part of a much larger project and have simplified the issue as far as possible. Note that the error is occuring inside of *void getthenumberhere...* where it is unable to detect the getIDnumber function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(int);
    ~Person();
    vector<RECT>* processrectangles;

    int Person::getIDnumber();
private:
    int IDnumber;

};

Person::Person(int x)
{
    IDnumber = x;
}
Person::~Person()
{
}

int Person::getIDnumber() {
    return IDnumber;
}

void getthenumberhere(vector<Person>* thisone) {
    int outID = *thisone[1].getIDnumber(); //IT CANT FIND THIS FUNCTION
}


int main() {
    int NextID = 1;

    vector<Person> People;
    Person newguy(1);
    People.push_back(newguy);
    getthenumberhere(&People);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Counting starts with `0` in programming, so you should use `(*thisone)[0].getIDnumber()`

Comment: Just a comment: if you're doing C++, include `cstdlib` and `cstdio` instead of `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` (and `cmath` instead of `math.h` if you uncomment the line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets to avoid ambiguity:

`((*thisone)[1]).getIDnumber();`

You can also do

```
thisone->operator[](1).getIDnumber();
```

as suggested in the comments.

Also, while declaration write this:

`int getIDnumber();`

instead of `int Person::getIDnumber();`. You shouldn't use resolution operator while declaring the member functions.

Comment: Also `->` is part of the game.

Comment: @skypjack Can you suggest how to use `->` in this case?

Comment: @user3286661 `[]` is also known as `operator[]` and it's a member method you can invoke as any other one.

Comment: @skypjack Please tell me the correct syntax because `v->[index]` doesn't compile.

Comment: @user3286661 You can still call the operator via its name, like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TuU3EGFWnhr4XgpN). Does not look all to clear to me though tbh.

Comment: @user3286661 As I said in the previous comment, use `operator[](index)`.

Comment: @user3286661 The syntax is more `v->operator[](index)`, but `(*v)[index]` looks simpler to me

Comment: `thisone->operator[](1).getIDnumber()` doesn't look at all more readable that what I wrote in the answer.